# Trace every object's load and store in java

Tags: java, instruments, instrumentation

Is there some way to trace every object's load and store operation in JAVA?

After this I also want to insert some self-defined function between the given JAVA code without manual modification.

So is there some easy way to achieve these?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Look into the proxy mechanism: https://dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java

Comment: Looks like you are looking for something like aspect oriented programming. It allows you to identify particular objects and the decorate them with custom functionality you need.

Comment: Uh... in fact I just want something like LLVM.